# Aerospike query language operate command

Tags: aerospike

I am trying to run aerospike query language operate command given at [Operate on a record](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/record_operations.html#operate-on-a-record)

> aql> OPERATE INCR(mybin,1) ON
>   test.demo where PK = 'key1'

But I get the following error

> ERROR: 404: COMMAND NOT FOUND : OPERATE

My client version is as follows:

> Aerospike Query Client Version 3.13.0.1 C Client Version 4.1.6

Eventually, I am trying to increment a record value.

Comment: What version of AQL are you using? Also, are you using AQL just to test Aerospike? This is the kind of thing you should generally be writing a program for with Java, Python, Go, or whatnot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you're using Aerospike Tools >= [3.15.0.3](https://www.aerospike.com/download/tools/latest) . CDT operations and others were added in that release; see the [release notes](https://www.aerospike.com/download/tools/notes.html).

Answer (score 3):

Type help on aql prompt. Those are all the commands available to you along with examples on how to use them.

```
$ aql
aql> help
```